# How to store value to a variable from SQL Query in Stored Proc in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying somw thing like inside a stored proc. But, I am getting error like incorrect

syntax near select statement.

```
declare @var int
@var=select max(id) from table1 where sname=@'XXX'
```

Comment: USE OUTPUT parameters IN Stored Proc

Comment: `SET @var = (SELECT ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the SET keyword, and have an extra @ you dont need. Additionally, I have wrapped the Select command in brackets.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @var int
SET @var=(SELECT max(id) FROM table1 WHERE sname='XXX')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @var int

select @var = max(id) from table1 where sname='XXX'
```